# How to run examples in lucene in action book

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am reading lucene in action book. There is a example provided in the book for indexing txt files. I need to try the example.Where to run the program or how to run the program in eclipse? I am using Windows do I need any IDE to run this programs. Is eclipse enough?

Comment: After you asked again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595642/compile-failed-when-running-a-lucene-example are you planning to leave this question dangling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the source code of "Lucene in Action, 2nd Edition". It contains everything you need, from Ant build.xml file to README where it tells how to run the examples.

And since Eclipse has a built-in support for Ant, then Eclipse is more than enough to run the examples.