# Compile failed when running a lucene example

Tags: java, junit, lucene

After fixing the error like tools.jar and junit.jar not found (thanks to stack overflow) I tried to compile the example given in "lucene in action" book. But when I compiled I am getting this error. Can you tell what error I am getting and how to fix it?

---

```
Total time: 0 seconds

E:\LuceneInAction>ant Indexer
Buildfile: E:\LuceneInAction\build.xml

check-environment:

compile:
[javac] E:\LuceneInAction\build.xml:66: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not
set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 104 source files to E:\LuceneInAction\build\classes
[javac] E:\LuceneInAction\src\lia\analysis\AnalyzerUtils.java:3: warning: [d
eprecation] Assert in junit.framework has been deprecated
[javac] import junit.framework.Assert;
[javac]                       ^
[javac] E:\LuceneInAction\src\lia\handlingtypes\html\NekoHTMLHandler.java:18
: error: package org.apache.html.dom does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.html.dom.HTMLDocumentImpl;
[javac]                           ^
[javac] E:\LuceneInAction\src\lia\analysis\AnalyzerUtils.java:90: warning: [
deprecation] Assert in junit.framework has been deprecated
[javac]     Assert.assertEquals(strings.length, tokens.length);
[javac]     ^
[javac] E:\LuceneInAction\src\lia\analysis\AnalyzerUtils.java:93: warning: [
deprecation] Assert in junit.framework has been deprecated
[javac]       Assert.assertEquals("index " + i, strings[i], tokens[i].termTe
xt());
[javac]       ^
[javac] E:\LuceneInAction\src\lia\handlingtypes\html\NekoHTMLHandler.java:32
: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]       new HTMLDocumentImpl().createDocumentFragment();
[javac]           ^
[javac]   symbol:   class HTMLDocumentImpl
[javac]   location: class NekoHTMLHandler
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 2 errors
[javac] 3 warnings

BUILD FAILED
E:\LuceneInAction\build.xml:66: Compile failed; see the compiler error output fo
r details.

Total time: 2 seconds
```

---

Sorry I dont have enough reputaion to post image

Comment: You have to add junit and other missing jars(see the errors) to your build path.

Comment: @Drogba I added junit to E:/ant/lib. Do I need to add any other jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tt is complaining about your jar which contains `HtmlDocumentImpl` not being on the `classpath`. Maybe `xerces`? A specific version.
The JUnits are a warning that it the `Assert` which comes from `org.framework`. You can update your JUnit jar file or leave it as is since that isnt the cause of the error.

The errors are due to a jar not being on your classpath. which in my guess is `xerces`

Comment: what I need to do. Sorry I am a complete noob on this

Comment: add the `xerces` jar which contains the `HtmlDocumentImpl` class just the way you added `jUnit` to it.